# Keyframing problem. Adds keyframes on all objects instead of the one that I selected

Tags: animation, text-object

So I have some text that I have made into a mesh and split up by loose parts.
And the problem is that whenever I try to add a location Keyframe Blender adds a keyframe to every letter instead of just the one that I have selected.
Here Is the .blend file [image]

Comment: We will need more information and a screenshot I think

Comment: Recorded a short video of the problem Uploading done in 10 min. When I add a Keyframe To the letter C It Adds  a keyframe on all the letters. And when I move  one of the letters it moves them all, But they are all different objects.Thanks for the quick reply.  @NoviceInDisguise  EDIT: Could you please tell me what you want a screenshot of, I am a bit of a blender beginner. Thanks Again.

Comment: What you have selected when you add the keyframe would be a good start

Comment: Okay so [THIS](http://imgur.com/qkZTTau)Is what I have selected. @NoviceInDisguise

Comment: Are you using the graph editor to add the keyframes?

Comment: No I select the C and then I press "I"And select position. @NoviceInDisguise

Comment: Please upload your .blend file to [**Blend-Exchange**](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and post the link in your question (you can edit it). This could be several things, but I can't be sure which, and it is much quicker to just browse through than to comment back and forth

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TIc_ZFyBNg)Is the video. It might help. @NoviceInDisguise

Comment: Okay. There you go :D @NoviceInDisguise

Comment: Taking a look now. BTW, the video did help too, that is exactly what I wanted. Just a note, you can use liceCAP or GifCam to record to a native animated GIF file which can be embedded directly int he post as an image.

Comment: Found the problem :D Posting an answer

Comment: One question, did you use `edit mode > [select vertices] > P > Separate by Selection`?

Comment: No, I used seperate by loose parts and Specials > remove doubles @NoviceInDisguise

Comment: And that would be your problem, the meshes are still linked. Using separate by selection worked perfectly for me

Comment: Ahaa, Thank you sooo much, you don't believe how helpful this was :D @NoviceInDisguise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking in the *Dope Sheet* and by experimenting with the keyframes, I can tell that the meshes have been linked at some point along the creation process. I tried the same thing with a new text object I made, and it worked perfectly. The method I used was to convert the extruded text to a mesh, then in edit mode select each character and press <kbd>P</kbd> *> Separate By Selection*.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful. And it works perfectly now. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: No problem :) It is a little bit of a pain to have to separate each character, so it would be nice if the other method could work. I'll keep experimenting

Comment: Sound awesome ;D

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned in the other answer, the animations of the separate objects are still linked.

You can see this if you go to the 'Dopesheet' and change the view mode to 'Action Editor'. The action datablock, which stores the animation, has '13' next to it showing that all 13 characters of text are using this shared animation:

[image]

To make all the objects animations separate you can select all the objects in the 3D view and do <kbd>U</kbd>> *Object Animation*. Now you can edit all the animations separately.

You could also do this individually by clicking on the '13' next to the action name, which creates a copy of the animation data, but you would have to do this on each object.

Comment: need to run through it a couple of times to figure it all out ...thanks... for future readers look at the action name `TextAction` as example in the image attached to this answers.