# Split Object moves independently but renders as one object?

Tags: rendering

I have a part that I have split into"loose parts".
When I try to animate it into individual elements it looks like its working, I set the timeline up and lock the location.
When I check the render, all parts move with it to the new keyframe?
How do I get a single item to move independently once rendered?
Note: I do not have proportional editing selected.

Images separated
[image: Images Separated[![enter image description here]

via Loose parts
[image]

Comment: Existing Keyframes will override whatever other moves you made unless you set new keyframes (or delete the current ones).

Comment: I am setting new keyframes, the part has roughly 30 individual parts, I moved them all into a line (like a exploded view) but when I roll the animation, all parts move to the same point as the first part that I set a keyframe for.

Comment: Hard to guess without more info.Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add detailed information on how you set up your projectand keyframes. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: While rendering objects will use animated position, if you move object which have keyframes and don't keyframe new position old one will be rendered instead

Comment: Does my answer on this question help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30318/keyframing-problem-adds-keyframes-on-all-objects-instead-of-the-one-that-i-sele/30861#30861